# Javascript callback function and parameters

Tags: javascript, callback, dom-events

I want to something similar to this:

```
function AjaxService()
{

 this.Remove = function (id, call_back)
 {
    myWebService.Remove(id, CallBack)
 }

 function CallBack(res) {
        call_back(res);
    }  
}
```

so my calling program will be like this:

```
var xx  = new AjaxService();
xx.Remove(1,success);

function success(res)
{


}
```

Also if I want to add more parameters to success function how will I achieve it. 
Say if I have success function like this:

```
var xx  = new AjaxService();
//how to call back success function with these parameters
//xx.Remove(1,success(22,33));

function success(res,val1, val2)
{


}
```

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use a closure and a function factory:

```
function generateSuccess (var1,var2) {
    return function (res) {
        // use res, var1 and var2 in here
    }
}
xx.Remove(1,generateSuccess(val1,val2));
```

What you're passing here is not the `generateSuccess` function but the anonymous function returned by `generateSuccess` that looks like the callback expected by `Remove`. `val1` and `val2` are passed into `generateSuccess` and captured by a closure in the returned anonymous function.

To be more clear, this is what's happening:

```
function generateSuccess (var1,var2) {
    return function (res) {
        // use res, var1 and var2 in here
    }
}
var success = generateSuccess(val1,val2);
xx.Remove(1,success);
```

Or if you prefer to do it inline:

```
xx.Remove(1,(function(var1,var2) {
    return function (res) {
        // this is your success function
    }
})(val1,val2));
```

not as readable but saves you from naming the factory function. If you're not doing this in a loop then Xinus's solution would also be fine and simpler than my inline version. But be aware that in a loop you need the double closure mechanism to disconnect the variable passed into the callback function from the variable in the current scope.

Comment: there are less complicated ways to do this in javascript, don't you think?

Comment: @parminder Are you sure it doesn't work? This is the standard way to pass arguments to callbacks that doesn't accept arguments, for example passing arguments to `setTimeout`. Is there something you may have missed form the syntax?

Comment: @harshath.jr  There's nothing complicated about this.  It's pretty standard JavaScript

Answer (score 8):

You can pass it as anonymous function pointer

```
xx.Remove(1,function(){
                           //function call will go here
                           success(res,val1, val2);
                      });
```

Comment: should be: `xx.Remove(1,function(res){success(res,val1,val2)});`

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this:

```
function AjaxService {
    var args_to_cb = [];
    this.Remove = function (id, call_back, args_to_callback_as_array) {
        if( args_to_callback_as_array!=undefined )
            args_to_cb = args_to_callback_as_array;
        else 
            args_to_cb = [];
        myWebService.Remove(id, CallBack)
    }

    function CallBack(res) {
       setTimeout( function(){ call_back(res, args_to_cb); }, 0 );
    }  
}
```

So you can use it like this:

```
var service = new AjaxService();
service.Remove(1,success, [22,33]);

function success(res,val1, val2)
{
    alert("result = "+res);
    alert("values are "+val1+" and "+val2);
}
```

I usually have the callback execute using a `setTimeout`. This way, your callback will execute when it gets the time to do so. Your code will continue to execute meanwhile, e.g:

```
var service = new AjaxService();
service.remove(1, function(){ alert('done'); }); // alert#1
alert('called service.remove'); // alert#2
```

Your callback will execute after alert#2.

Of course, in case of your application, it will happen so automatically since the ajax callback itself is asynchronous. So in your application, you had better not do this.

Cheers!
jrh

Comment: in CallBack function reference to call_back doesnt exists
how it will be called.

Comment: JS tends not to use patterns like this; generally any other state is wrapped in a closure.