# jQuery HOW TO?? pass additional parameters to success callback for $.ajax call?

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

I am trying, in vain it seems, to be able to pass additional parameters back to the success callback method that I have created for a successful ajax call.  A little background.  I have a page with a number of dynamically created textbox / selectbox pairs.  Each pair having a dynamically assigned unique name such as name="unique-pair-1_txt-url" and name="unique-pair-1_selectBox" then the second pair has the same but the prefix is different.

In an effort to reuse code, I have crafted the callback to take the data and a reference to the selectbox.  However when the callback is fired the reference to the selectbox comes back as 'undefined'.  I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997531/javascript-callback-function-and-parameters) that it should be doable.  I have even tried taking advantage of the 'context' option but still nothing.  Here is the script block that I am trying to use:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
function getImages(urlValue, selectBox) {
    $j.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $j(urlValue).val(),
        dataType: "jsonp",
        context: selectBox,
        success:function(data){
         loadImagesInSelect(data)
        } ,
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }

    });
}

function loadImagesInSelect(data) {
var select = $j(this);
select.empty();
$j(data).each(function() {
    var theValue = $j(this)[0]["@value"];
    var theId = $j(this)[0]["@name"];
    select.append("<option value='" + theId + "'>" + theValue + "</option>");
});
select.children(":first").attr("selected", true);

}    
</script>
```

From what I have read, I feel I am close but I just cant put my finger on the missing link.  Please help in your typical ninja stealthy ways.  TIA

****UPDATE****
Nick is a true Ninja.  They should invent a new badge for that!  His answer below does the trick.  As he mentions it's 1.4 specific but I can live with that.  Here is my final code that is working for any Ninjas in training (and my future reference):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
function getImages(urlValue, selectBox) {
    $j.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlValue+ '?callback=?',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        context: selectBox,
        success: jQuery.proxy(function (data) {
            var select = $j(this);
            select.empty();
            $j(data).each(function() {
                var theValue = $j(this)[0]["@value"];
                var theId = $j(this)[0]["@name"];
                select.append("<option value='" + theId + "'>" + theValue + "</option>");
            });
            select.children(":first").attr("selected", true);
        }, selectBox),
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: looks correct, are you getting any errors in the console? can you also paste the code where the call to `getImages(urlValue, selectBox)` is being made?

Comment: no errors in the console.  Just on the callback selectBox is undefined.  The call to the method looks like this:
getImages($j('[name=txt_registry_url]').val(),$j('[name=.selImageList]'))

Comment: maybe its too obvious, but does this selector work `$j('[name=.selImageList]')) `? Based on the code, if nothing changes during the ajax call, `selectBox` should work as expected. Try logging selectBox at various points and check if the issue is it being undefined in the success callback, the loadImagesInSelect function, or maybe even getImages.

Comment: sorry fat fingered.  it should read: getImages($j('[name=txt_registry_url]').val(),$j('[name=selImageList]')).  But as I mentioned, the getImages method is passed the proper reference and I can inspect the default values in the debugger to verify.  The reference is there all the way until the callback then it becomes undefined.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18570951/885464

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Updated:** If you're using jQuery 1.4 use this to simplify things a bit:

```
success: jQuery.proxy(function (data) {
    var select = $j(this);
    select.empty();
    $j(data).each(function() {
        var theValue = $j(this)[0]["@value"];
        var theId = $j(this)[0]["@name"];
        select.append("<option value='" + theId + "'>" + theValue + "</option>");
    });
    select.children(":first").attr("selected", true);
}, selectBox)
```

Comment: Nick,  This does not seem to work.  I first tried with the anonymous method and still nothing.  I can see the method getting invoked but cannot step into the anonymous method.  So I changed it to use the external method so I could break on it.  It then comes back undefined.

Comment: @dotnetgeek - How are you calling the external method?  It should just be `success: externalMethodName` with a signature like this: `function externalMethodName(data)`

Comment: @Nick, I updated the original code with how I currently have it setup. It looks like this: loadImagesInSelect(data, $j(this)).
Wether I pass it the reference or not, $j(this) returns back a Window object.

Comment: @dotnetgeek - That's the part I'm trying to convey, you don't control which arguments are passed to that function, the format is always `function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)`, but you can determine what `this` refers to inside that function by setting `context: something`, that `something` will be `this` when the function runs.

Comment: When I do what you suggest, change the callbacck method format to:
loadImagesInSelect(data)
and change the loadImagesInSelect method to:
function loadImagesInSelect(data) {
    var select = $j(this);
    select.empty();
    $j(data).each(function() {
        var theValue = $j(this)[0]["@value"];
        var theId = $j(this)[0]["@name"];
        select.append("<option value='" + theId + "'>" + theValue + "</option>");
    });
    select.children(":first").attr("selected", true);

}

$(this)'s type is NOT the dropdown.  In IE it shows as DispHTMLWindow2.  In FF its a Window

Comment: @dotnetgeek - In hopes you're using jQuery 1.4, updated the answer with a more reliable method to go about it, see if it gives you any trouble.

Comment: @Nick, you da man!  This example is working perfectly.  I think the previous would have worked too.  The key change in addition to your suggestion was changing the param that I passed to the JSONP service.  I originally had: "http://<url>:<port>?callback=loadImagesInSelect"   I changed that to "http://<url>:<port>?callback=?".  Thanks a million for your persistence and patience!  I will update my question with the full proper code.

Comment: @dotnetgeek - Welcome :) Glad this version's working, easier to understand as well I think, once you use proxy just a handful of times.

Comment: Great stuff Nick! I just used jQuery.proxy with the .each() on a jQuery UI plugin I'm currently working on. Works wonders, and is my new favorite function. jQuery.bind was my old fav. But now all jQuery events carry the ability to add pass in addition data.

Answer (score 24):

This is what I did, and it also worked fine:

```
$.ajax('URL', {
    myCustomControl: selectBox,
    myCustomVariable: 'teste',
    data:
    {
       myData: 1
    },
    success: function (data, textStats, jqXHR) {
        myFunction(data, textStats, jqXHR, this.myCustomControl, this.myCustomVariable);
    }   
});
```

You can add controls and variables to the parameters of your ajax call.

Comment: tested in chrome, with jquery-1.11.2
seems like, you dont really need the object:

`function ajaxParameterTest(p1, p2)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Download.aspx?status=true",
        success: function(data, status, jqXHR){
                    callbackFunction(data, status, jqXHR, p1, p2);
                 },
        dataType: "html",
        statusCode:{
            404: function(){
                alert("you cannot retrieve data from the server right now..");
            }

        }   
    });
}`

Answer (score 14):

Put this into your $.ajax parameters.

```
invokedata: {
    data1: "yourdata",
    data2: "moredata"
}
```

In the success function use it like this

```
this.invokedata.data1;
this.invokedata.data2;
```

Your $.ajax call and the success function must also be a part of the same object. Put your functions in an object and define them like this

```
function myObject {
    var getImage = function(..) { }
    var loadImagesInSelect = function(..) { }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what you mean by: Your $.ajax call and the success function must also be a part of the same object? Also I do not see invokeData as a parameter on the jQuery site.  Can you elaborate on the values?  Do they need to be strings or can they be an object reference?

Comment: I have updated my answer. invokedata is stored in your object, not in jquery. Data can be anything.

Comment: I was not able to get this working but @Nick's final answer seemed to work.  Thanks for the help though.  Your solution has given me a couple more ideas to try out to clean things up a bit.

Comment: Check this answer, which worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542208/how-to-refactor-this-javascript-anonymous-function/2542323#2542323. I was trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

## `this` is Out of Scope

Just so you (or anyone else) understand(s)<sup>1</sup>, the reason that `this` was undefined in `loadImagesInSelect()` in your original example was because that function was under a different scope, and scopes don't "cascade" like that<sup>2</sup>.

When you specified a "context" of `selectBox` in your AJAX call, it set the context (`this`) for the functions given to "success" and "error". (It just so happens that they were both anonymous functions.) At this point, `this` is defined in both of these functions, as the value of `selectBox`. Now, in the function passed to "success", you call `loadImagesInSelect()`. When you call a function, it creates a new scope. In this scope, `this` will be `window` in non-strict mode and `undefined` in strict mode.

---

### Put Graphically (in Strict Mode<sup>3</sup>):

```
// this = window (global scope)

$j = jQuery.noConflict();
function getImages(urlValue, selectBox) {

    // this = undefined (function scope level 1)

    $j.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $j(urlValue).val(),
        dataType: "jsonp",
        context: selectBox,
        success: function(data) {

            // this = selectBox (function scope level 2)

            loadImagesInSelect(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

            // this = selectBox (function scope level 2)

            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
}

function loadImagesInSelect(data) {

    // this = undefined (function scope level 3)

    var select = $j(this);
    select.empty();
    $j(data).each(function() {
        var theValue = $j(this)[0]["@value"];
        var theId = $j(this)[0]["@name"];
        select.append("<option value='" + theId + "'>" + theValue + "</option>");
    });
    select.children(":first").attr("selected", true);
}
```

---

### `$.proxy()` is Redundant

The use of `$.proxy()` in your updated code is redundant. You use `$.proxy()` to get `this` to the function that was formerly called `loadImagesInSelect()`, but you moved that function up into "success" anyway (instead of calling it from within "success"). It already has access now to the value of `this` specified by "context".

**You could remove the `$.proxy()` wrapper around your "success" function in your updated code and it would still work.**

I know it's been years since you asked your question, but I hope this helps.

---

1. I hope this doesn't come across as condescending; it's not meant to be.
2. At least, not when you *call* a function, and not with context. If you define a function within a function (i.e. a closure), then any variables in the outer function will be available in the inner function. **However**, the outer function's context (the `this` variable) still isn't available in the inner function.
3. Replace `undefined` with `window` for non-strict mode.
4. Or the native `Function.prototype.bind()` in ECMAScript 5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **indexValue** attribute for passing :

```
var someData = "hello";

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3",
    indexValue: {param1:someData, param2:"Other data 2", param3: "Other data 3"},
    dataType: "script"
}).done(function() {
    console.log(this.indexValue.param1);
    console.log(this.indexValue.param2);
    console.log(this.indexValue.param3);
});
```