# javascript - sending a parameter to a function

Tags: javascript, events, parameters

I have this:

```
var MyObject = {};

MyObject.doStuff = function(someParam) {
   var webdav = new Webdav("addr","port");    

   var handler = {
      onSuccess: MyObject.Success,
      onError: MyObject.Fail
   }

   webdav.PUT(handler, filename, options);
}

MyObject.Success = function(result) {
    alert('status ' + result.status + result.statusstring);
}
```

I'm using [exo platform](http://wiki.exoplatform.org/xwiki/bin/view/WS/JavaScript%20WebDAV%20Library) javascript library for webdav access (if it matters)

The handler I'm creating will call `MyObject.Success` if `webdav.PUT` is done succesfully. How can i send the `someParam` to that function too?

Put in another way, after a successful or failed operation, I'm interested in doing something with the `someParam`, depending of the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you'r looking for:
[javascript callback function and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997531/javascript-callback-function-and-parameters)

or maybe: 
http://onemarco.com/2008/11/12/callbacks-and-binding-and-callback-arguments-and-references/

```
var someParam = 'foo';
var handler = {
     onSuccess: function(result) {success(result, someParam);},
     onError: function() { fail(); }
    }
```

Comment: Did you borrow from me, or do we have the exact same style to javascript? :-) Or wait, I just edited mine - and it looks like yours!

Answer (score 1):

You should look into javascript objects, and try to contain the code within one scope. Something like this:

```
var MyObject = {

    var doStuff = function(someParam) {
        var webdav = new Webdav("addr","port");    

        var handler = {
          onSuccess: function(result) {success(result, someParam);},
          onError: function() { fail(); }
        }

       webdav.PUT(handler, filename, options);
    }

    var success = function(result, someParam) {
        alert('status ' + result.status + result.statusstring);
    }

    var fail = function() {}

    this.doStuff = doStuff;
}

var myObj = new MyObject();
myObj.doStuff(param);
```

Comment: with closures, the someParam will be available in the onSuccess handler

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do it, taking advantage of JavaScript closures:

```
var handler = {
   onSuccess: function(result) { MyObject.Success(result, someParam); },
   onError: MyObject.Fail
}
```