# Javascript callback function with parameter?

Tags: javascript

I have this simple code :

```
console.log('calling doWork func...')
doWork('a', 'b', myCb);

function doWork(param1, param2, callback)
{
        console.log('in func')
        callback();
}


function myCb(a)
{
        console.log('in callback... for value ' + a)
}
```

I'm running the  function with a callback function  -

The output I get is :

```
"calling doWork func..."
"in func"
"in callback... for value undefined"    // notice the undefined
```

All ok.

Now, I want the callback to be called with a *specified param*   - something like ( which is incorrect since the `()` is executing the func) :

```
doWork('a', 'b', myCb('xxxx'));
```

I want the output to be :

```
in callback... for value  xxxx
```

How do I send a parameter with the myCb call  in     `doWork('a', 'b', myCb);`? *( 'when you run the callback function , please run it according to value xxxx')*

any help ?

p.s. I want to avoid any *global flags solution*

thanks.

Comment: may be duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997531/javascript-callback-function-and-parameters

Comment: @mask8 please search the term `.bind` in your link , I *don't* see it. so I assume it is not duplicate ( different solutions)

Comment: how about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458553/javascript-passing-parameters-to-a-callback-function there are too much of this questions anyway

Comment: @mask8 Ok , Agree. ( didnt find it before though) ...:)

Comment: @RoyiNamir when that first question was written, ES5 had been approved [less than a month prior](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/PressReleases/PR_Ecma%20approves%20major%20revision%20of%20ECMAScript.htm). At that time, most browsers didn't support it, and most developers weren't familiar with it.  The lack of `.bind` in the answers is definitely not suggestive that it is not a duplicate (and *certainly* not conclusive in any case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common solution is to create another function in place.

```
doWork('a', 'b', function () {
    myCb('xxxx');
});
```

You can also use a function that would abstract the [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) away. JavaScript (ES5) even has one built-in – [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Mind you, the native `bind` will make your callback slow and has limited support in browsers (see the MDN page).

```
doWork('a', 'b', myCb.bind(null, 'xxxx'));
```

Comment: What are the issue(s) with the native bind?

Comment: @pst, while binding a context, it also allows `call` and `apply` to redefine it dynamically. Try to implement such `bind`, and you'll see. That makes each call to a bound function slow. [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/artificial-vs-native-bind/3)

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions is to use `.bind`:

```
doWork('a', 'b', myCb.bind(null, 'xxx'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use apply and arguments

```
console.log('calling doWork func...')
doWork('va', 'b', myCb);

function doWork(param1, param2, callback)
{
        console.log('in func')


        callback.apply(this,arguments);
}


function myCb(a)
{
        console.log('in callback... for value ' + a)
}
```

[JSbin](http://jsbin.com/ejuqak/1/edit) Example

Comment: oh i see, i mistook the a, from cb with the first argument, you want to pass to the cb function
then this won't help you

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log('calling doWork func...')
doWork (myCb, "a", "b");
function doWork (callback) {
console.log('in func')
callback (arguments[1], arguments[2]);
}
function myCb (param1, param2) {
console.log('in callback... for value ' + param1)
}
```

Hope this help you